# Delphi: How to Input data into an record array using two for loops?

Tags: arrays, delphi, input

I have a problem where inputting data into a record array, it crashes once i get past the 5th input, and i do not understand why. I have a for loop inside a `for` loop as seen, and were the data is being inputted depends on the `for` loop which is not working

```
uses
 System.SysUtils;

type
  TPerson = record
    Name: string;
    Friends: array of TPerson;
  end;


var
  Paul: TPerson;
  A,B:Integer;
begin

 SetLength(Paul.Friends, 5);
 SetLength(Paul.Friends[0].Friends, 5);
 SetLength(Paul.Friends[1].Friends, 5);

for A := 1 to 5 do
   begin
     for B := 1 to 5 do
       begin
        writeln('Input data');
        readln(Paul.Friends[A].Friends[B].Name);
      end;
    end;

   end.
```

The crash just says windows has detected a problem and the program freezes up.

Comment: I don't understand which part you're having trouble with. Looks like working code to me.

Comment: @JerryDodge It just crashes for me!?

Comment: Where does it crash? It doesn't crash for me. Although I can't make sense out of what the code is doing. It asks me for some input 5 times and then exits gracefully, no errors. Where does it "Crash" for you?

Comment: Are you typing non-numerical values?  You're expecting integers and are not checking them... are you trying to input text perhaps?  If you would tell us what the error you are receiving is we would be better able to help.  Something like `Project Project1.exe raised exception class EInOutError with message 'Invalid numeric input'.`, perhaps?

Comment: @J Sadly, the question doesn't even mention any "error" or "crash" - it came later in the comments.

Comment: Read what you wrote in your last sentence (*once I get to the 6th variable*), and then look at the value you used for `SetLength` (which is not **6**). Also, dynamic arrays start at index 0, not index 1.

Comment: @KenWhite I understand that but the system you still run 25 times overall, why isn't it doing that?

Comment: Because you're doing it wrong. But I can't answer the question until you improve the question and get it reopened; answering in the comments would defeat the whole purpose of closing poor quality questions. If you want an answer, [edit] your question and improve it so it gets reopened. (Or use the debugger and figure it out yourself by stepping through the code.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues with the code you've posted.

- You're allocating the arrays wrong
- Your loop is incorrect when accessing the arrays
- Dynamic arrays start with index 0, so you're exceeding the array length

Here's an example of properly initializing (and reading back) from the arrays as you're intending. I'll leave it to you to convert the first loop to reading input from the console. It was compiled and tested as written in a Delphi XE7 console application.

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TPerson = record
    Name: string;
    Friends: array of TPerson;
  end;

var
  Paul: TPerson;
  A,B:Integer;
begin
  Paul.Name := 'Paul';
  // Initialize Paul's Friends
  SetLength(Paul.Friends, 5); 

  // Initialize each of Paul's friends Friends 
  for A := 0 to 4 do
    SetLength(Paul.Friends[A].Friends, 5);

  for A := 0 to 4 do
  begin
    Paul.Friends[A].Name := Format('Friend %d', [A]);
    for B := 0 to 4 do
      Paul.Friends[A].Friends[B].Name := Format('Friend %d of friend %d', [B, A]);
  end;

  // Write out what we did with the code above    
  for A := 0 to 4 do
  begin
    WriteLn(Paul.Friends[A].Name);
    for B := 0 to 4 do
      WriteLn(Paul.Friends[A].Friends[B].Name);
  end;
  ReadLn;

end.
```